# Dot Product - How does it help to define whether the light source hits my object or not?

Tags: graphics, 3d

For example the light source is coming from 1,3,-5 and object is at 4,-2,-1.

> Algebraic formula is going to give the answer as 3.  [1,3-5].[4,-2,-1]
>   = 1*4 + 3*-2 + -5*-1 = 3

But what does this 3 means? How do I know if my object is shaded with this number 3? Or is there more to it? I did look around and unable to find anything conclusive. Would be great if someone could give some insight. Thank you.

Judging from answers, pondering if I am understanding my question wrong. I was trying to get my head around the following question:

> For a point on a convex surface, with the normal n=(n1,n2,n3)and light
>   direction l = (l1,l2,l3), determine if the point can be seen by light
>   source.

Comment: Are you sure `4,-2,1` is the position of the object? It makes much more sense to me if was the surface normal. Same for the light source.

Comment: Hi, seems I got it wrong. But even then when position is reversed, I don't get how the calculation helps in me finding out if the light hits the object.

Comment: @keshk do you know what the normal is? It is a vector that is perpendicular to the plane of the triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a dot product between two points makes no sense. Essentially, a dot product gives a measure of how similar two vectors are. When applied to points, the value will be related to the similarity of the direction to the points from the origin, as well as their distance from it. That metric doesn't make much sense, as you found out with that '3'.

To determine the amount of illumination, you want to be using a dot product between the normalized vector of the direction from the surface to the light and the surface normal. The result will be a value from -1 to 1, which you can interpret as an illumination factor for simple gouraud shading. In pseudocode:

```
illumination = max(0, dot(normalize(lightPosition - positionOnSurface), surfaceNormal))
```

Determining if a light hits an object is an entirely different problem called occlusion, and not really something you express in as mathematical formula. It's about testing what objects are in the path from the light to your target object.

Answer (score 0):

The dot product can tell you on what side of a line a point is. The triangle is formed by three lines. If you are on the same side of all three lines then you are inside the triangle. You can use three dot products to test for each of the three sides. See slide 23 on this link http://comp575.web.unc.edu/files/2010/09/06raytracing1.pdf.

Comment: I updated the question. Wondering if I was not supposed to be using Dot product in the first place.

Comment: The normal vector defines a plane. The only way the light vector will not hit that plane is if it is parallel to it, in which case the dot product between the normal and the light direction will be zero.